# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET And backend side Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am working on MEAN application its simple registration and login application
i am trying to save post via form and i m getting this error after submitting form in console: HttpErrorResponse of angualr as well as backend console i m getting  if(err) throw err;
                    ^
Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string

I follow angular 2 tutorial but i m using angualr 6
here is the tutorial link `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFftMN32jyQ&list=PLillGF-RfqbZMNtaOXJQiDebNXjVapWPZ&index=7`

## auth.Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

   authToken: any;
   user: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    registerUser(user){
     let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register','user', {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res);



  }

}
```

## register.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ValidateService } from '../../services/validate.service';
import { AuthService  } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages/module/flash-messages.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  name: String;
  username: String;
  email: String;
  password: String;


  constructor(private validateService: ValidateService, private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
    private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onRegisterSubmit(){
    const user = {
      name: this.name,
      email: this.email,
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }

    //Required Field
    if(!this.validateService.validateRegister(user)){
      //console.log('Please Fill in all feilds');
      this.flashMessage.show('Please Fill in all feilds',{cssClass:'alert-danger', timeout: 3000});
     return false;
    }
     //Required Email
     if(!this.validateService.validateEmail(user.email)){
     // console.log('Please use a valid email');
       this.flashMessage.show('Please use a valid email',{cssClass:'alert-danger', timeout: 3000});
      return false;
    }
     //Register User
     this.authService.registerUser(user).subscribe(data =>{
         if(data){
          this.flashMessage.show('You are now registered and can log in',{cssClass:'alert-success', timeout: 3000});
          this.router.navigate(['/login']) ;
        }else{
          this.flashMessage.show('Something went wrong',{cssClass:'alert-danger', timeout: 3000});
          this.router.navigate(['/register']) ;
         }
     }); 

  }

}
```

## register.component.html

```
 <h2 class="page-header">Register</h2>
<form (submit)="onRegisterSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Any help is highly  appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be posting the string "user" and not the object user from your incoming variable.

this:

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register','user', {headers: headers})
```

should be this:

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user, {headers: headers})
```